# How to give '>' as parameter to terminal in python

Tags: linux, terminal, python

I was wondering if you could help me with a problem:

in python I've been trying to give '>' to the subprocess.Popen([]) or subprocess.call([]), but somehow it changes the way it is entered in the terminal. An example.

Terminal command:

```
iperf -s -u -y C > data.csv
```

Python code:

```
import subprocess as sub

sub.Popen(['iperf', '-s', '-u', '-y', 'C', '>', 'data.csv'])
```

or

```
sub.Popen(['{iperf', '-s', '-u', '-y', 'C}', '>', 'data.csv'])
```

When I run the first command in the terminal, it will execute just fine, but when I execute the second one, it will literally ignore the '>' and 'data.csv':

```
$ python test.py
iperf: ignoring extra argument -- >
iperf: ignoring extra argument -- data.csv
```

And the third command returns:

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    sub.call(['{iperf', '-s', '-u', '-y', 'C}', '>', 'data.csv'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried searching DuckDuckGo and Google for this problem, but I can't find an answer because they won't interpret the '>' symbol, even when used as ">".

I look forward to your answers, thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The > is interpreted by the shell not by the program. Since subprocess doesn't use a shell by default, the > is passed directly to the program. Using `shell=True` might work, but to redirect `stdout`, you should use the `stdout` argument.

For example, you could use

```
import subprocess

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    subprocess.Popen(['iperf', '-s', '-u', '-y', 'C'], stdout=f)
```

Comment: One last simple question: I take it 'w' stands for write?

Comment: Yes, 'w' opens the file for writing, creating it if it doesn't exist and truncating it if it does. This is documented in the open documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the command as a string, and signal to `subprocess` that's a shell command with `shell=True`:

### source

```
import subprocess

print subprocess.call([
    "echo beer > zoot"
], shell=True)
```

### output

```
0
```